# How to reuse function type inside a component for other components props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

How can I declare my props to use a type definition of a function declared inside another component ?

In the example below, how can I tell `onUpdate` to be the same definition as the `onUpdate` function defined in `index.js` ?

```js
// index.tsx
interface UIState {
    position: number
}

const Provider = () => {
    const onUpdate = <T extends keyof UIState>(property: T, fn: (ui: UIState) => UIState[T]): void => {
        // some cool function logic here..
    }

    return <Entry onUpdate={onUpdate} />
}


// Entry.tsx
const Entry = ({ onUpdate }: { onUpdate: /* ??? */) => {
    const onClick = () => {
        onUpdate('position', ui => ui.position + 1);
    }

    return <div onClick={onClick} ></div>;
}
```

Of course I could reuse the same definition, but meh. that's just straight duplication

```js
const Entry = ({ onUpdate }: { onUpdate: <T extends keyof UIState>(property: T, fn: (ui: UIState) => UIState[T]) => void }) => {
```

Should I declare the function definition outside the component ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it a `type` to reuse it again and again like this:

```
type TUpdateFn<T extends keyof UIState> = (property: T, fn: (ui: UIState) => UIState[T]) => void
```

and use it like this:

```
const Entry = ({onUpdate}:{onUpdate: Tupdate}) => {
 // your logic here
}
```

Comment: I am happy to help